# Ultisnips: using common snippets for C and C++

Tags: plugin-ultisnips

By default my Ultisnips (or maybe it's Vim) associate *.h* files with C++ snippets.

I was about to ask how to make how to make Ultisnipps associate *.h* files with *c* types, but then I realized that my C snippets are valid for C++, so my question is how can I use common snippets for C and C++ ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

UltiSnips has the `extends` keyword. You pass a comma separated list of filetypes to it and it will load the snippets for those filetypes before the snippets in the file the keyword is used in.

Example:

> extends c, obj-c

This way you can have a "cpp.snippets" file which "extends" your c filetype and obj-c type. The documentation doesn't mention cyclic extending but it will probably get in a loop and break something so don't do that. I'm pretty sure you can use a fake filetype so you can do something like this:
 - create a snippet file called "cgeneral.snippets" which shouldn't get loaded by UltiSnips automatically
 - create your "c.snippets" file
 - add "extend cgeneral" at the top (can actually be anywhere in the file)
 - repeat for "cpp.snippets"
Now you can have all general stuff in "cgeneral" and import that into your c.snippets file and your cpp one, too.